# Using row reduction to solve for a variable in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

With given column vectors *x* = [1,3,2], *y* = [3,1,2], and *z* = [7,*a*,6], I need to use row reduction to find the value of a such that the vectors {*x*, *y*, *z*} are linearly dependent.

I am seeking to understand how to find this variable via row reduction. I reduced the matrix entirely to RREF when I remembered that I was supposed to be solving for *a*. Could I get some assistance?

Comment: What is the value of the determinant of the matrix formed by the three vectors above? For what $a$ can you force this determinant to be non-zero?

Comment: @Kevin The determinant is 4a - 20. The. determinant is non-zero for all values except a = 5.

Comment: @aoajimin_  So at $a=5$ determinant is zero; means the vectors are linearly dependent. That is what I showed.

Comment: @aoajimin_ If you find my answer useful, please upvote it. Somebody downvoted it, although the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A set of vectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ is linearly independent if the $c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n = 0 \implies c_i = 0$ for $i = 1, ..., n$. When row-reducing a matrix, you are essentially solving a system of equations like this and trying to show that there is only one solution s.t. all the unknowns of the system are $0$. If you pay close attention, you'll notice that a system has only one solution when the coefficient matrix is the identity i.e. if the system of equations being solved has one solution that is $0$ in every entry. Thus, a matrix $A \in R^{nxn}$ has linearly independent columns if RREF($A$) = $I_{nxn}$, where $I_{nxn}$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3& 2\\3 & 1& 2\\7 & a& 6 \end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3& 2\\0 & -8& -4\\0 & a-21& -8 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3& 2\\0 & -8& -4\\0 & a-21+16& -8+4*2 \end{pmatrix} $, so $a=5$

Comment: What is wrong here?